# Can I use a CFast 1 card reader to read a CFast 2.0 memory card?

Tags: digital, file-management, computer-hardware

CFast 1 uses the SATA II interface while CFast 2.0 uses the new(er) SATA III interface. SATA III is backwards compatible with SATA II but does that mean I can use a CFast 1 card reader to read a CFast 2.0 memory card? Or are the physical components just completely different?

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot use a CFast 1 card reader to read a CFast 2.0 memory card. CFast 2.0 cards have a different physical and data interface, and they are not backward compatible with CFast 1 card readers. You will need a CFast 2.0 card reader to access the data on a CFast 2.0 memory card.

Comment: CFast uses SATA which is fully backward and forward compatible. I hope you have a specific proof that it's not the case. I tried to find compatibility claims but can't.